# C++ calling member function without circular inclusion

Tags: c++, directx

I'm working on DirectX9 and building an Basic OOP system for handling the draw/update loop.

So i have 3 classes `DirectXGame`,`D3DWindow`,`DemoGame : public DirectXGame` so as you can see the the `DemoGame` extends the `DirectXGame` class. and demo game has an instance of `D3DWindow` inside it as window.

So D3DWindow create a Windows Window and sorts out starting up DirectX inside the window or Full screening it.

so I have created `void(*drawEvent)(int dt)` & `void(*updateEvent)(int dt)` and some setters(`addDraw, addUpdate`) that should allow `DirectXGame` to pipe the methods into the `D3DWindow` object

```
void DirectXGame::createWindow(D3DWindow* wind, HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShowD)
{
    this->d3dWindow = wind;
    this->d3dWindow->create(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShowD);
    /*below is lines 26 and 27 from errors*/
    this->d3dWindow->addDraw(this->draw);
    this->d3dWindow->addUpdate(this->update);
}
```

however all i get is errors

```
C3867: 'DirectXGame::draw': function call missing argument list; use '&DirectXGame::draw' to create a pointer to member directxgame.cpp 26
C3867: 'DirectXGame::update': function call missing argument list; use '&DirectXGame::update' to create a pointer to member directxgame.cpp 27
```

i can't pass &DirectXGame::update or DemoGame::update as these would not have access the the member variables so how can i get this to work.

now i have been reading around and finding stuff like forwarders but to do that i have to cast to `DirectXGame` inside `D3DWindow` and this causes a header to be needed and subsequently inclusion loop problem.

if you need to see any more code please ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an interface with 2 pure abstract methods 'draw' and 'update'.
D3DWindow holds an pointer to an instance of this interface (your DirectXGame instance) and calls 'draw' and 'update' on it.

```
class IDirectXGame
{
public:
  virtual ~IDirectXGame() {}
  virtual draw(int) = 0;
  virtual update(int) = 0;
};
```

Inherit the interface

```
class DirectXGame : public IDirectXGame
{
  ...
};
```

D3DWindow holds an pointer to an instance implementing the interface.

```
class D3DWindow
{
  ...

  IDirectXGame *gameInstance;
};
```

In 'createWindow' just pass 'this' to the windows 'gameInstance' member.

Comment: do you know i had not even though of interfaces i thank you for that however this is what i get from that now.. `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall IDirectXGame::draw(int)" (?draw@IDirectXGame@@UAEXH@Z) DirectXGame.obj`

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten the '= 0' at the end of the interface method? the '= 0' makes this method pure virtual, that means child classes have o override it.